# Data entered to my database is something different from what I have entered into my mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, rest

```
 const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const app=express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cavadium',{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true});

// Create a new Schema

const itemSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    price:Number,
    imageUrl:String
});

// Create a mongoose model

const Item=mongoose.model('Item',itemSchema);

// GET ALL ARTICLES FOR OUR LISTING PAGE

app.get('/products',function(req,res){
    Item.find(function(err,foundItems){
        // console.log(foundItems)
        res.send(foundItems);
    });
});

// POST ALL ARTICLES FROM OUR ADMIN PANEL

app.post('/products',function(req,res){
    const newEntry=new Item({
        name:req.name,
        price:req.price,
        imageUrl:req.imageUrl
    });
    newEntry.save(function(err){
        if(!err)
            res.send('Item added successfully');
        else
            res.send(err);
    });
});

app.listen(8000,function(){
    console.log(`Server online at port no. 8000`);
})
```

So basically I am trying to enter data using this API, but although data is being entered successfully when I make the get request, then I receive a response

[
{
"_id": "5efa42c392b93f99747b99ec",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5efa461c0999a149ac696b06",
"__v": 0
}
]

I don't understand what is happening

Comment: This is a post request are you sure that you are getting data using req.name. Better to put console logs and check for the data that what you are receiving is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating empty records in DB.

While saving data in POST API handler, fetch fields from "req.body" object. For eg: `req.body.name` instead of `req.name`.

Comment: Thank Your very much